# WCF URL Question

Tags: wcf, azure, wcf-binding

I'm somewhat new to web development, so I'm unsure of the terminology to use here.  I have a wcf web service that I've build for windows azure.  I would like to have multiple endpoints that resolve to the same service, however I'm not entirely sure how to configure this.

This may help explain what I'm wanting a little better:

Currently, I have a service at https://myapp.cloudapp.net/service.svc

I would like to have the following url point to the same service in the application:

https://myapp.cloudapp.net/myapp/service.svc

I'm sure this is something easy to do, I just haven't been able to find a solution yet.

Edit:

I found this documentation on MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734786.aspx

However, I can't seem to get it to work.

Here is is how my endpoint is defined in my web.config:

```
<services>
   <service behaviorConfiguration="MetadataEnabled" name="myProject.myApp.myService">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="https://localhost/myService/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsBinding" name="wsBase" contract="myProj.myApp.IServ" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" bindingConfiguration="mexBinding" name="HttpMetadata" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <endpoint address="myApp/" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsBinding" name="WsPlain" contract="myProj.myApp.IServ" />
  </service>
</services>
```

It's still not working, but hopefully it's getting close.  Would love any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out the answer.  I just needed to create a folder in the project "myApp", and make copy the .svc file (not the .svc.cs file) to that folder.  This allowed the following to work:

myapp.cloudapp.net/service.svc
myapp.cloudapp.net/myapp/service.svc

Answer (score 0):

There's a [WCF Routing Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd795218.aspx) that might be of use (or might be overkill).

See also [Supporting Multiple IIS Site Bindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358763.aspx) and [Endpoint Addresses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751841.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I looked at several of the samples, but none of them seem to tackle what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

This is trivial and probably you already do, but are you defining InputEndpoints in ServiceDefinition.csdef?

Comment: Yes.  My input endpoint looks like this:     <Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="HttpsIn" protocol="https" port="443" certificate="my-cert-name" />
    </Endpoints>